El host byethost7 de la API en PHP requiere Javascript para devolver JSON con solicitud GET desde C# y FORMS en aplicación de escritorio
Subí la API creada en PHP a byethost7 y al consumirla con peticiones GET o POST recibo la siguiente respuesta

function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return
e}function toHex(){for(var
d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;fd[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return
e.toLowerCase()}var
a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("c710049f0ef2450a7751728043c66d39");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+";
expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
location.href="http://mipagina.byethost7.com/miapi/api.php?i=1";This
site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your
browser or use a browser with Javascript
support

Estaba investigando y por algunas respuestas del 2015 ese hosting tiene seguridad antibots por lo que pide cookies, ¿Pero como obtengo las cookies si haga la petición desde una aplicación de escritorio?
Realmente desconozco de APIS y este proyecto es el primero que hago haciendo peticiones a una API, la api la hice en PHP para uso con MySQL, existe alguna solución? o será cuestión de cambiar de hosting y en todo caso que así sea a cual sería, pueden dar alguna recomendación?
Gracias de antemano.
EDIT:
En respuesta al comentario de @A.Cedano y para aclarar un poco más, la api si la pruebo en el navegador me envía sin problemas los resultados, aquí esta la respuesta a una solicitud GET de prueba

Estos a continuación son los errores en C#:


pero en C# al obtener el JSON me arroja el error que puse antes, e investigando como dije, al parecer es por ser plan gratuito ningún hosting permite el uso de APIS fuera del navegador ya que están pensados para alojar sitios web en su versión gratuita, pagando creo que se consigue, igual encontré una respuesta en StackOverflow en ingles que agregando Exit() en la API se evita la seguridad antibots, pero ya probé tampoco me resultó. Saben si hay solución o si se debe pagar? la verdad no puedo pagar por ahora un hosting.
Gracias.

Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. Explica tu infraestructura. ¿Es un dominio alojado en un servidor remoto? Si es así, harás las peticiones a la API mediante una URL, y la puedes probar en el navegador para ver las respuestas, por ejemplo, esta URL es una llamada a la API de Github que muestra los usuarios. Luego, puedes autentificar si es preciso con API Keys. En cuanto a consultarla desde una App de escritorio, eso ya depende de en qué lenguaje vas a programar dicha App, pues hay varias herramientas para consultar APIs remotas según lenguaje de programación.

@A.Cedano Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si claro, puedes ver  la imagen que agregué haciendo la consulta desde el navegador como se ve la API arroja el registro que tengo de prueba, pero necesito hacer las peticiones desde C#, usando XAMPP en el desarrollo para el localhost todo está bien con las deserializaciones y serializaciones JSON, solo el problema ese al hacer la petición en el host byethost7. Gracias de nuevo.

@A.Cedano hice una segunda edición para agregar más detalles con imágenes. Gracias.

Un status 200 NO es un error. Indica que la petición tuvo éxito. Ahora tienes que echar mano de alguna herramienta para manejar la respuesta de esa petición y/o mapear la respuesta a una clase de tu modelo de datos si fuera preciso. Yo no programo en C#, así que no puedo decirte lo que ese lenguaje podría usar para manejar respuestas de APIs, pero seguro que esa herramienta existe, como existe para la mayoría de lenguajes. Si algún experto en C# pasa por aquí, espero que te diga algo o investiga en la red.

La captura de abajo, hace pensar que tu servidor no está devolviendo un JSON en la URL que estás consultando, sino un contenido HTML. En el servidor tú debes programar para que en vez de HTML devuelva un JSON. Son dos ámbitos de programación distintos: 1. La aplicación de escritorio, que en tu caso será en C#, pero que puede ser un varios lenguajes; 2. El funcionamiento en el servidor (que se conoce como backend) y que escribirás, supongo, en PHP. El ejemplo que te puse de Github es una API que puede consumirse desde cualquier aplicación, escrita en cualquier lenguaje.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

es simple, el request del navegador al implementa una serie de headers por defectos del navegador, y en tu app de escritorio parece no estar presentes, el hosting reconoce esto y al paracer cancela o responde con mensajes de error ... y parece que el principal es que la app de escritorio no reporta tener javascript activado ...

Esto no tiene nada que ver con php ni con el api... esta relacionado al hosting y request realizado por la aplicacion de escritorio.

@FranciscoNuñezIALover Hola, si, es como lo mencionas, el hosting está solicitando unas cookies y JavaScript para poder devolver el JSON, haciendo pruebas con este sitio https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts no tengo ningún problema, la aplicación carga el JSON en mis controles. Sabes que puedo hacer para solucionarlo? como mencioné es un plan gratuito e investigando parece que todos los hosting tiene ese candado en planes gratuitos, pero no se que tan correcta es esta afirmación ¿?. Gracias por tu respuesta.

tendrias que publicar el codigo C# de la aplicacion de escritorio que es la que se encarga de esto ... ya que la config del hosting gratuito no la podes cambiar ... lo otro seria cambiar de hostina uno de pago para entorno de desarrollo un shared hosting deberia funcionarte

@FranciscoNuñezIALover Muchas gracias, creo que ya sabia eso, pero tenía un poco de fe que podría existir alguna solución, aun así te agradezco para ya no buscar alguna solución y perder el tiempo, será cuestión de ver los planes de pago de cada servicio de hosting.  Si publicas tu comentario como respuesta a la pregunta para que te de flecha arriba e igual para quien tenga un problema similar encuentre a la vista esa conclusión. Gracias de nuevo.

Porque la gente piensa que puede romper la seguridad de un hosting que pone justamente eso, para que justamente no hagas eso, porque justamente es la forma en que ellos se ganan la vida??? La solucion es pagar lo que corresponde por lo que se usa... ;)

Agrega la URL para realizar pruebas

estudiando los comentarios y lo que indicas, en tu post no hay ningun error de codigo que resolver, las alternativas apuntan a que debes crear un nuevo post donde publiques el problema con el codigo C# que es el responsable de emitir los request, esta no es una solucion pero si el camino para un parcheo ...
por otro lado si no quiere tocar la aplicacion den C# lo otro que puede hacer es indagar o cambiar de hosting gratuito a un de pago, por lo menos un shared hosting realtivamente barato te debe servir para alojar el entorno de desarrollo, con esto tendrias la facilidad de manipular el API y el entorno webserver.
Ten en consideracion que la respuesta es seguir mejorando las aplicaciones que tienes a mano y hacer un work around de las limitaciones que presentas...
O apegarte a los estandares, buenas practicas y pasar por caja ... como te han respondido antes, este es un feature de seguridad no tiene sentido desactivarlo.
